# Is there a name for this manga-anime mouth expression? (`3`)

Tags: tropes

Is there a name for this expression?

They do it a lot in YuruYuri, too.

[image: (°3°)]

Comment: Related question [Why do character eyes change into lips when they take their glasses of](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21862/when-characters-take-off-their-glasses-why-do-their-eyes-turn-into-a-lip-eyes)

Comment: The character Kuga from *World Trigger* would often exhibit the "3-mouth* as well.  At times, it seemed to be his normal, resting, expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a pout, and is based on the real life expression of the same name.

While it can be used as way of making oneself look more attractive, it's more often used (especially in anime) as a childish way of expressing displeasure or annoyance, in a similar way to the [puffed out cheeks expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uCBr.jpg).

See [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pout) and [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pout) for additional definitions.

The "3 face pout" is an exaggerated form of a pout, and there are other less extreme cases to be found elsewhere. Some examples of varying intensity are included below.

[image: Pout 1]

[image: Pout 3]

Additionally, the "3-face" is not limited to only a pout. As a shorthand form of displaying puckered lips, it can also be seen upon characters either awaiting or giving a kiss, or on those whistling.

Comment: I'd say it is a [duckface](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Duckface), more than a pout...

Answer (score 6):

ヾ( ˙³˙ )ﾉﾞ The so-called "3 face" is really just an emote expression, and doesn't really have an official term, so to speak.

The Japanese refer to it as "口が3" or "the mouth is (a) 3," so you could call it a "3 mouth."

Basically it's an expression that originates from manga expressing puckered lips. How it's used can vary.

A "3 mouth" can be used to indicate dissatisfaction or otherwise, (sharp) displeased emotion.

(๑ •̆ ૩•̆)

The "3 mouth" can also indicate pucking lips such as indicating or preparing recieving a kiss.

(ㅅ ´ ³ ` ) ~♡

Additionally characters some time use the "3 mouth" when whistling or blowing (i.e. exhaling), both activity involve puckering lips.

(;￣з￣) ～♪～♪

It can also be used to indicate a blank, neutral expression in a silly way.

(・ε・)